# Finding a Change of Basis Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the best way to go about finding a change of basis matrix? For example, I am trying to find the change of basis matrix from one basis of $\mathbb P_2$ to another basis. Is there any good, simple, systematic way of doing this?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you write $\mathbb P^2$, you are asking for a change of basis matrix for the _projective plane,_ not for the two-dimensional vector space $\mathbb R^2$--is that right? For a two-dimensional vector space there is a unique $2\times2$ matrix for any change of basis, but for the projective plane you need a $3\times3$ matrix, and it is not unique; any non-zero scalar multiple of the same matrix will do as well IIUC. If you really want $\mathbb P^2$ and not $\mathbb R^2$ it might be well to put the words "projective plane" in the question _and_ in the title.

Comment: See page 11 of http://morpheo.inrialpes.fr/people/Boyer/Teaching/M2R/geoProj.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It’s often trivial to find the change-of-basis matrices between the given bases and a standard basis for the vector space—usually just a matter of writing the basis vectors down as columns of the matrices. Once you have these, you only need to invert one and multiply them together. The only mildly tricky part is sorting out which one should be inverted and the order in which to multiply them. You can find an example of this method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1501205/265466). Note that you don’t need a “standard” basis for the vector space. As long as you can find the coordinates of both bases relative to some other common basis, you can apply this method.

In general, the entries of the change-of-basis matrix which maps $\phi$-relative coordinates to $\psi$-relative coordinates are the coefficients $m_{ij}$ of the system of linear equations $$\begin{align}
\phi_1 &= m_{11}\psi_1 + m_{12}\psi_2 + \cdots + m_{1n}\psi_n \\
\phi_2 &= m_{21}\psi_1 + m_{22}\psi_2 + \cdots + m_{2n}\psi_n \\
& \vdots \\
\phi_n &= m_{n1}\psi_1 + m_{n2}\psi_2 + \cdots + m_{nn}\psi_n,
\end{align}$$ i.e., the columns of the matrix are the coordinates of the $\phi$-vectors relative to the $\psi$-vectors. This suggests another way to compute the invert-and-multiply of the previous paragraph: form the augmented matrix $$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|cccc}|&|&&|&|&|&&| \\ \psi_1 & \psi_2 & \cdots & \psi_n & \phi_1 & \phi_2 & \cdots & \phi_n \\ |&|&&|&|&|&&| \end{array}\right]$$ and row-reduce. The change-of-basis matrix will be on the right side after row-reduction. Using the same example, we form the matrix $$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}\frac12 & -\frac12 & \frac1{\sqrt2} & 0 \\
\frac{\sqrt3}2 & \frac{\sqrt3}2 & 0 & \sqrt{\frac32}\end{array}\right],
$$ which, after row-reduction, becomes $$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}1&0 & \frac1{\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt2} \\
0&1 & -\frac1{\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{array}\right].
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you provide an example (or a link to one) of how to do this?

Comment: Also, if the matrix I find works for one example, do I know that that is the correct matrix?

Comment: @MathLogic See the updated answer for an example. If you choose the test case carefully, you can be pretty confident that the matrix you computed is correct.